# converting decimal to int in c#

Tags: c#

why percentage returns 0 when rate = 0.085 for example ?

```
int percentage = (int)rate*100;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The cast operation is applied before the multiplication.  Try:

```
int percentage = (int)(rate*100);
```

Edit:  Here's the C# guide on [order of operator evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173145%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

It returns 0 because of order of operations.  `rate` is cast as an integer prior to multiplying.

You need an extra set of parentheses to make this work.

`int percentage = (int)(rate*100);`

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
int percentage = (int)(rate * 100);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
int percentage = (int)(rate*100);
```

You're converting `rate` to an int BEFORE you multiply it otherwise.